# How to change jquery code to javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular6, angular7

I am trying to change jquery code to javascript or typescript for working in angular 7 project. But i do know how to change it. If anyone know please help to find the solution?

```js
$("#mytableId").find('table').each("tr").find("td:first").click(function(e){
    
    alert($(this).text());  //getting first td value of each tr
    
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<custom-table id="mytableId">
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div> 
    <table>
    <thead>
    <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>189556</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>122586</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    
    </custom-table>
```

Comment: Angular and Jquery are fundamentally very different, I would suggest learning some basic angular before you'll be able to ask the right questions. There is no way to "convert" between the two.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound:Just i am asking How we can write same like that condition in angular 7?

Comment: @SpeedOfRound: Just tell me how to use viewchild and elementRef for that Or pure javascript

Comment: @SpeedOfRound: If you have same like this condition in your angular 7 project.. How you can manage it?

Comment: In Angular you use structural directives to build tables, you inject variables and handlers as you build the table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular event bindings to respond to any DOM event(click in your case). you can find the [documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).